# Reading metadata from existing datasets in ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcpy, metadata, arccatalog

I would like to know which ArcPy functions can be used to read metadata from existing datasets in ArcCatalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArcPy functions for working with metadata are found in the [Metadata toolset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-metadata-toolset.htm):

> All ArcGIS items have a description, which is also referred to as
> metadata. The Metadata toolset lets you handle metadata for ArcGIS
> items and stand-alone metadata XML files.

Each tool in the Metadata toolset has a Code Sample to illustrate how it can be used in ArcPy.

I am not a metadata expert but I think the tool you need first is [Validate Metadata](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/validate-metadata.htm) which:

> Exports metadata to a standard metadata format then validates the exported file.